# SoundWire server is already running

Tags: audio, mixing, monitoring

I use SoundWire software.

I want to launch multiple servers at once, so I could stream Audio to multiple channels to multiple users. It is written here http://georgielabs.net/SoundWireHelp.html that's it's possible. But when I launch via console SoundWire with different ports (as written in docs)

```
SoundWireServer –p 59010
SoundWireServer –p 59020
SoundWireServer –p 59030
```

I receive error: **SoundWire server is already running**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved as soon as I set SOUNDWIRE_SERVER_PORT enviroment variable. After that I could run multiple instances of SoundWire.

```
Network Port #: To change the network port number used by SoundWire Server set the environment variable SOUNDWIRE_SERVER_PORT to the desired number
```